# RUBY instance variable is reinitialized when calling another method

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

why is  the instance variable @my_instance return nil even thought it's been set to 0 in the my_method ?

attr_accessor should let me write and read the instance, right ?

what would be the right way to do something like this ?

thank You.

```
class Myclass

  attr_accessor :my_instance

  def initialize
    @my_instance
  end 

  def called_method
    puts "this is my instance value #{my_instance} "
  end 

  def my_method
    my_instance = 0
    puts "i set my instance to be #{my_instance}"
    called_method
  end 

end 

a = Myclass.new

a.my_method
```

called_method return nil when i expect 0

Comment: There _must_ be a good dup target already, but I couldn't find a suitable one with a short search :/

Comment: @Sergio has given a good answer but in future please consider waiting longer (at least a couple of hours, imo) before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and is imo discourteous to others still working on answers. There's no rush.

Comment: What's the purpose of your `initialize` method? It does exactly the same thing as your `my_instance` getter method, so what do you need it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what would be the right way to do something like this ?

```
my_instance = 0
```

This creates a local variable instead of calling your setter. Give ruby a hint that you want to call the method:

```
self.my_instance = 0
```

Or you can set the instance variable directly:

```
@my_instance = 0
```

Comment: @maxpleaner: in presence of the setter, why set instance variable directly? You're bypassing the level of indirection you yourself set up.

Comment: I'm not saying it's better or worse. Just pointing out that it is a possibility since OP clearly doesn't realize it.

Comment: @maxpleaner: fair enough